# Pegar id mais value digitado pelo usuario

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou montando uma tabela via JavaScript da seguinte maneira:

```
itens += '<table border="0" class="table table-hover ">'+
        '<thead>'+
          '<tr class="table">'+
              '<th style="text-align:center;" class="col-md-3">Descrição</th>'+
              '<th style="text-align:center;">Qtd</th>'+
          '</tr>'+
        '</thead>'+
        '<tbody>';
    $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "js/ajaxBuscarDados.php",
            cache: false,
            data: {id: id},
            success: function(data) {
              $('#modalAguarde').modal('hide');
              if(data.retorno == 'ERRO'){
                $('#modalAguarde').modal('hide');
                $('#modalErro').modal('show');
                $("#minhaTabela").html(itens);
              }else{
                itens += "<tr>";
                itens += '<td><input disabled type="text" class="form-control" id="descricao" readonly="true" name="title" placeholder="'+ data[i].descricao +'"></td>';
                itens += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qtd" name="qtd#'+data[i].id_i+'" value=""></td>';
                itens += "</tr>";
              }
              itens += "</tbody></table>";
              $("#minhadiv").html(itens);
              }
            }
    });
```

Agora vem o meu problema:
Quando realizo o submit do form, é me retornado vários campos qtd mais a numeração do ID da tabela. Seguido do seu respetivo valor informado pelo usuário.

Como eu consigo pegar o valor do ID mais o value que o usuário digitou?

**EDIT:**

Meu retorno no PHP: http://pastebin.com/W59yLR4L

Comment: Uma dúvida, o valor do ID não seria o que o user digitou ? Ou você se refere ao  nome dado ao "id"?

Comment: O campo data[i].id_i vem do banco de dados, é esse ID que preciso pegar junto com o valor digitado pelo usuário.

Hoje esta chegando assim pra mim qtd#1 -> 1 ---- qtd#2 -> 200 etc..

Comment: Bom eu não manjo de jquery, mas para pegar o valor dos inputs no puro js, vc pode usar: var valor_input = document.getElementById("id_do_input").value; e ai vc trabalha com a variável.

Comment: @MagicHat, obrigado, mas o value eu já consigo pegar, o problema é o ID que vem do banco de dados! Fiz uma atualização na minha pergunta com o resultado do meu submit

Comment: Fiz uma "gambiarra" colocando no campo value o ID, mas acaba aparecendo essa informação para o usuário, caso ele apague, ja era, vai da erro!

Comment: Vc pode usar o atributo "readonly" no input... é um dos caminhos...